# css - div overflowing outside of fieldset parent

Tags: html, css, overflow

jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/0q3ega2n/

I'm currently at a bit of a loss.  I have a fieldset that has a select box in its legend and is meant to dynamically update the content within my fieldset, which works fine.  For layout purposes, the fieldsets are fixed at a height of 200px.

Where I'm running into issues is adding scrollbars to the fieldsets in the event the content overflows.  I can't use an `overflow: auto` on the fieldset itself, because that causes the `legend` tag to scroll as well.  Some other answers suggested using a content wrapper `div` to add the scrollbars, which I've done.

However I'm still not quite where I want.  I need to specify a `height` attribute for the wrapper `div` in order for the overflow to occur.  Setting it to 100% results in text still overflowing outside the box (albeit not as much as it does with no overflow set).  Setting it to 92% is pretty much exactly what I want **but** 92% was chosen arbitrarily and as a result doesn't feel right (plus I'm slightly concerned about cross-browser compatibility)

CSS:

```
* {
  font: 12pt Verdana;
}

fieldset.metrics {
  height: 200px;
}

div.metrics-wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  height: 92%;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

HTML:

```
<fieldset class='metrics'>
  <legend>
    Fieldset Title, with a
    <select>
      <option selected='selected'>select box</option>
    </select>
  </legend>
  <div class='metrics-wrapper'>
    <p>
      Content goes here
    </p>
  </div>
</fieldset>
```

Comment: You're misusing the `legend`. It' supposed to be a **caption**. - Not another element - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/legend

Comment: While I appreciate the comment, this doesn't pertain to the issue.  Were I to use it as a caption (i.e. text only), the text in the legend tag will still scroll with the content actually contained within the fieldset, which is the issue I'm trying to prevent.

Answer (score 1):

The `metrics-wrapper` is still overflowing `metrics`
adding `overflow: hidden` fixes it

```
fieldset.metrics {
  height: 200px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

Comment: Great.  This gets me ~95% of the way there, thank you!  The last thing I want to do is add a 5px padding between the border of the fieldset and the bottom of the div, which is proving troublesome because of `metrics-wrapper` overflowing.  I've tried `padding-bottom` on the fieldset and also `margin-bottom` on the div, but no dice.